# Call to a member function find() on a non-object on line 423

Tags: php, arrays, simple-html-dom

I'm getting an error

> Call to a member function find() on a non-object in line 423.

I know there is an url as the key in the array because I test it and worked. Also used the line of code on 423 before and worked fine.

**Here is the code sample**

```
$oppo_team = array(teams::$ars_fixtures=>'Arsenal', teams::$manc_fixtures=>'Manchester City', teams::$che_fixture=>'Chelsea', teams::$liv_fixture=>'Liverpool', teams::$tott_fixture=>'Tottenham', teams::$eve_fixture=>'Everton', teams::$manu_fixture=>'Manchester United', teams::$newc_fixture=>'Newcastle United',
    teams::$south_fixture=>'Southampton', teams::$swan_fixture=>'Swansea City', teams::$ast_fixture=>'Aston Villa', teams::$nor_fixture=>'Norwich City', teams::$hull_fixture=>'Hull City', teams::$cry_fixture=>'Crystal Palace', teams::$westb_fixture=>'West Bromwich Albion', teams::$stoke_fixture=>'Stoke City',
    teams::$westh_fixture=>'West Ham United', teams::$ful_fixture=>'Fulham', teams::$sun_fixture=>'Sunderland', teams::$carc_fixture=>'Cardiff City');


 for ($i=0; $i < $lengthgp; $i++) { 
# code...
    if(!preg_match('/'.$home_team[$i].'/i', $team)){
        if($i == 0){

        }else if($i > 0){

        }

    }else{}

    if(!preg_match('/'.$away_team[$i].'/i', $team)){
        if($i == 0){

        }else if($i > 0){
        echo $oppaway[] = array_search($away_team[$i], $oppo_team);
            //}else{

            //}

            $oppfix = file_get_html($oppaway);

            //Collect scores from the sites table

            for($score = 1;$score<114;$score+=3){
            // Find within td a
    LINE 423---->   $oppa_scores = $oppfix->find('td a', $score);
            //store in array
                $oppgame_scores[] = $oppa_scores->plaintext;
            }
```

Add the array which the key is the links on separate class.

Comment: var_dump($oppfix) and tell us what is returned (is it an object?)

Comment: It returns boolean false

Comment: I var_dumped $away_team and a list came out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found out was that sometimes in simple_html_dom was that you need to check whether there is a url available even it there is one what happens if there isn't.

```
$oppfix = file_get_html($oppaway);

if(!exist($oppfix)){

        //Collect scores from the sites table

        for($score = 1;$score<114;$score+=3){
        // Find within td a
LINE 423---->   $oppa_scores = $oppfix->find('td a', $score);
        //store in array
            $oppgame_scores[] = $oppa_scores->plaintext;
        }
}else{
//Do SOMETHING
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if `$oppaway` is your URL, then change

```
echo $oppaway[] = array_search($away_team[$i], $oppo_team);
```

to

```
echo $oppaway = array_search($away_team[$i], $oppo_team);
```

The argument to `file_get_html` should be a string

Comment: you need to make sure that $oppaway is a valid url.

Answer (score 0):

Have you instantiated $oppfix with a class that contains the method "find"?